# Обработка нескольких форм JSP Java Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

На странице есть несколько форм, в зависимости от заполненной должна в качестве ответа конкретная страница, как обработать эти несколько форм?

mypage.jsp:

```
  <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
  <html>
  <head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .Show{
        border: 2px solid black;
        font-size: 35px;
        color: blue;
        background-color: yellow;
        width: auto;
        height: 80px;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    body{
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
    button{
        height: auto;
    }
    input{
        width:  220px;
        height: 30px;
    }
    div{
       width: 250px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="MyServlet" method="POST">
    <div class="Show">
         <label for="day">Введите день недели</label>
        <input type="text" id = "day" name="day"/>
        <label for="room">Введите аудиторию</label>
        <input type="text" id = "room" name="room"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
        <input type="reset" name="Очистка формы">
    </div>
</form>

<form action="MyServlet" method="POST">
   <div class="Show">
    Преподаватели не ведут занятия</br>
    <label for="day2">Введите день недели</label>
    <input type="text" id = "day2" name="day2"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
    <input type="reset" name="Очистка формы">
   </div>
</form>

<form action="MyServlet2" method="POST">
    <div class="Show">
    Дни недели</br>
    <label for="countLesson">Введите количество занятий</label>
    <input type="text" id = "countLesson" name="countLesson"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
    <input type="reset" name="Очистка формы">
    </div>
</form>

<form action="MyServlet" method="POST">
    <div class="Show">
    Дни недели</br>
    <label for="countRoom">Введите количество аудиторий</label>
    <input type="text" id = "countRoom" name="countRoom"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
    <input type="reset" name="Очистка формы">
    </div>
</form>

<form action="MyServlet" method="POST">
    <div class="Show">
    Перенос занятий</br>
    <label for="firstDay">Перенести с</label>
    <input type="text" id = "firstDay" name="firstDay"/>
    <label for="secondDay">на</label>
    <input type="text" id = "secondDay" name="secondDay"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
    <input type="reset" name="Очистка формы">
    </div>
</form>
```

Класс обработки:
MySerlet.java:

```
@WebServlet("/")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    req.getRequestDispatcher("mypage.jsp").forward(req, resp);

}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String day = req.getParameter("day");
    String room = req.getParameter("room");
    AbstractList<com.art.servlet.ResultSet> result1s = new ArrayList<com.art.servlet.ResultSet>();

    if(day!=null  && room!=null) {
        try {
            getInstanceDatabase();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ResultSet resultSet = GetInformationDatabase("SELECT shedule.fio, shedule.name, shedule.day, lessons.room FROM lb7.lessons INNER JOIN lb7.shedule ON lessons.day = shedule.day WHERE ( room = '" + Integer.parseInt(room) + "' and lessons.day = '" + day + "') ");
        resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        resp.getWriter().println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
        try {
            if(!resultSet.next())
            {
                resp.getWriter().println("<html><body><p> По вашему запросу ничего не найдено!</p></body></html>");
            }
            else {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    com.art.servlet.ResultSet result = new com.art.servlet.ResultSet();
                    result.setFio(resultSet.getString("fio"));
                    result.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
                    result.setRoom(resultSet.getString("room"));
                    result.setDay(resultSet.getString("day"));
                    result1s.add(result);
                }
                req.setAttribute("list", result1s);
                req.setAttribute("day",day);
                req.setAttribute("room",room);
                req.getRequestDispatcher("Result1.jsp").forward(req, resp);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    String day2 = req.getParameter("day2");
    System.out.println(day2);
    if(day2 != null) {
        try {
            getInstanceDatabase();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ResultSet resultSet = GetInformationDatabase("SELECT DISTINCT fio FROM lb7.shedule where day != '"+ day2 +"'");
        resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        resp.getWriter().println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
        try {
            if(!resultSet.next())
            {
                resp.getWriter().println("<html><body><p> По вашему запросу ничего не найдено!</p></body></html>");
            }
            else {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    com.art.servlet.ResultSet result = new com.art.servlet.ResultSet();
                    result.setFio(resultSet.getString("fio"));
                    result1s.add(result);
                }
                System.out.println(result1s.size());
                req.getRequestDispatcher("Result2.jsp").forward(req, resp);
                req.setAttribute("list2", result1s);
                req.setAttribute("day2", day2);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Попробовал создать 2 класс MyServlet2 аналогичный MyServlet посыпались ошибки

Comment: Можно в каждую форму включить `<input type="hidden" name="form" value="form1"/>` с разным `value` для разных форм. И по нему определять какая форма отправлена. Можно сделать `submit` с разными `value` : `<input type="submit" name="form" value="form1">Отправить</input>`. И тоже на сервере по этому значение распознать какая из форм отправлена.

Comment: Каким образом распознавать на сервере?

Comment: Обычным `if ("form1".equals(req.getParameter("form"))) { ... } else if ("form2".equals(req.getParameter("form"))) { ... } ...`